# Combining potentiometers to register as buttons

Tags: python, pi-3b+

Does anyone know how I could use 2 potentiometers (1 for vertical axis, other for horizontal) and combine them to register as buttons? I want to make a shifter for sim racing and I want to combine 2 potentiometers. One for moving the stick forward and backward, the other for moving it left and right. So, if I want to shift gears to first gear, one potentiometer would register the stick moving to the left and the other would register the stick moving forward, shifting the in game car to first gear. I want racing games to register the input of changing gears as buttons so it's easy to set up.
BTW, I'm using raspberry pi 3B+

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not just use a rotary switch? You can get them about the same size as potentiometers. I'm not sure how you plan to turn your stick movement into rotation, but that's an aside.

Comment: I could do that, but actually my main concern is how I can use the raspberry pi to control games. Any clue on how to do that?